# CSS - Hover over any element to trigger transitions on all of them

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm creating a website and I'm making the header in a table, where each column is a different section, the plan is the top row is a picture link and the bottom row is the name of that section... also a link (although I haven't actually gotten around to making them links yet). If I strip down the table to it column looks vaguely like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100px; max-height: 100px" id="header-games-button"><img src="header-games.png" class="header-icon block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="header-games-text" class="headermidrow">Games</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS (it's a mess, I'm sure):

```
.header-icon{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.block{
    display: block;
}

.headermidrow{
    height: 20px;
}

#header-games-button{
    background-color: #fca93e;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
    transition: background-color .2s;
}

#header-games-button:hover{
    background-color: #fc8e00;
}

#header-games-text{
    background-color: white;
    color: #fca93e;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s;
    transition: color .2s;
}

#header-games-text:hover{
    color:#fc8e00;
}
```

So to get to the point: I want to be able to hover over either the icon or the text link and have both of their transitions play to change them to their hover colours. I've looked around and I can't seem to find anything that I can make work (I've tried a bit of CSS and a bit of jQuery).

A pure CSS solution would be great but JS/jQuery is fine too if that's the best way to do it. Also I'm open to re-enginerring the whole part (just started and the design isn't set in stone) if it'll make my job any easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `table:hover` to get what you have mentioned.

### CSS

```
/*
#header-games-button:hover{
    background-color: #fc8e00;
}
#header-games-text:hover{
    color:#fc8e00;
}*/

table:hover #header-games-text {
    color: #fc8e00;
}
table:hover #header-games-button {
    background-color: #fc8e00;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that was a thing. I simplified my example a little too much -  I have multiple columns with different things, so I don't want to :hover the whole table or they all light up, but I can just use nested tables to get it to work how I want.